# How to return records by another column id from same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

T1 **Heroes**

```
ID    NAME FRIEND
001   TOM  NULL
002   JEK  NULL
003   MAX  001
004   JIZ  NULL
005   ZAK  002
```

How to return all friends?

Result should be like:

```
001 TOM NULL
002 JEK NULL
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Heroes
WHERE ID in ( SELECT * FROM Heroes WHERE ID IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: The subquery is expected to return only one column, the one to be compared with ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, you just need to pick the right column in the subquery:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM Heroes h
WHERE h.ID IN (SELECT h2.friend FROM Heroes h2);
```

I prefer `EXISTS` for this purpose:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM Heroes h
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT h2.friend FROM Heroes h2 WHERE h2.friend = h.ID);
```

This often has better performance.  But `IN` is fine.